# why doesn't col("^") work as expected

Tags: vimscript

I know that there is a function `col({expr})`, which returns the column position given with `{expr}`.

For example, `col("$")` gives me the column position of the end of the cursor line.

So I thought `col("^")` can give me the column position of the first non-whitespace character of the cursor line. But `col("^")` always return `0`.

```
if xxx
    hello|<here is the cursor> world
endif
```

In the example above, when I execute `:echo col("^")`, I always get a `0`, instead of `4`.

Why? BTW, 4 spaces or a tab before the `hello` make no difference.

And if `col("^")` can't give me the column position of the first non-whitespace character, how could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I thought col("^") can give me the column position of the first non-whitespace character of the cursor line. But col("^") always return 0.

That's a fair assumption, but `'^'` is not documented at [:h col()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#col()):

```
col({expr})     The result is a Number, which is the byte index of the column
                position given with {expr}.  The accepted positions are:
                    .       the cursor position
                    $       the end of the cursor line (the result is the
                            number of bytes in the cursor line plus one)
                    'x      position of mark x (if the mark is not set, 0 is
                            returned)
                    v       In Visual mode: the start of the Visual area (the
                            cursor is the end).  When not in Visual mode
                            returns the cursor position.  Differs from '< in
                            that it's updated right away.
```

IOW, passing `'^'` to `col()` is an error, and the latter returns 0:

```
The first column is 1.  0 is returned for an error.
```

> And if col("^") can't give me the column position of the first non-whitespace character, how could I get it?

Try this:

```
echo getline('.')->match('^\s*\zs\S') + 1
```

For more info, see:

- [:h getline()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getline())
- [:h method](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#method)
- [:h match()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#match())
- [:h /\s](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%5Cs)
- [:h /star](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/star)
- [:h /zs](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%5Czs)
- [:h /\S](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%5CS)

Answer (score 1):

> So I thought col("^") can give me the column position of the first non-whitespace character of the cursor line.

For me it's hard to imagine why you think so. `^` is a normal mode command, it's nowhere said it would be accepted by `col()`.

> how could I get it?

Well, the easiest way is `indent('.') + 1`, but, in fact, it gives `virtcol()`, not `col()`. Sometimes it's good, sometimes not. So if you need `col()` for real, you have to invoke `match(getline('.'), '\S') + 1`.

Comment: Well, I often use `^` and `$` together. That's why I thought `col("^")` and `col("$")` should work.

Comment: @Yves Accepted parameters are listed under `:h col()` as usual. If you believe `^` must be there, why not also `_`, and `g^`, and `g$` and myriad of others?

Comment: Because I haven't noticed that the list is the ONLY accepted expr...

Comment: @Yves In IT sphere (as in a few others) pessimism prevails. Every time one sees docs claiming "that thing works", he should read "it's the ONLY thing that MAYBE working" instead.

Comment: @Matt As an IT professional let me just say...LMAO!